# MPI error while loading shared libraries: libpgftnrtl.so in another machine

Tags: mpi, openmpi, hpc

I built [MPI](https://www.mpich.org/static/downloads/3.3.2/mpich-3.3.2-installguide.pdf) in one of my linux (ubuntu) machine (SOL), it works OK on this machine. Only SOL has all complier libs

```
./mpiexec -n 8 -f machinefile /usr/apps/lib/mpich-3.3.2-pgf_gcc/examples/cpi
Process 0 of 8 is on SOL
Process 6 of 8 is on SOL
Process 1 of 8 is on SOL
Process 7 of 8 is on SOL
Process 3 of 8 is on SOL
Process 2 of 8 is on SOL
Process 4 of 8 is on SOL
Process 5 of 8 is on SOL
pi is approximately 3.1415926544231247, Error is 0.0000000008333316
wall clock time = 0.001447
```

machine file

```
SOL: 8
```

However, when I tried running MPI on two machines
machine file

```
SOL: 4
Corona:4
```

Corona cannot find lib needed,

```
stilocal@SOL:/usr/apps/lib/mpich-install/bin$ ./mpiexec -n 8 -f machinefile /usr/apps/lib/mpich-3.3.2-pgf_gcc/examples/cpi
/usr/apps/lib/mpich-3.3.2-pgf_gcc/examples/.libs/lt-cpi: error while loading shared libraries: libpgftnrtl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/apps/lib/mpich-3.3.2-pgf_gcc/examples/.libs/lt-cpi: error while loading shared libraries: libpgftnrtl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/apps/lib/mpich-3.3.2-pgf_gcc/examples/.libs/lt-cpi: error while loading shared libraries: libpgftnrtl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/usr/apps/lib/mpich-3.3.2-pgf_gcc/examples/.libs/lt-cpi: error while loading shared libraries: libpgftnrtl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
^C[mpiexec@SOL] Sending Ctrl-C to processes as requested
[mpiexec@SOL] Press Ctrl-C again to force abort
[mpiexec@SOL] HYDU_sock_write (/usr/apps/lib/mpich-3.3.2/src/pm/hydra/utils/sock/sock.c:256): write error (Bad file descriptor)
[mpiexec@SOL] HYD_pmcd_pmiserv_send_signal (/usr/apps/lib/mpich-3.3.2/src/pm/hydra/pm/pmiserv/pmiserv_cb.c:178): unable to write data to proxy
[mpiexec@SOL] ui_cmd_cb (/usr/apps/lib/mpich-3.3.2/src/pm/hydra/pm/pmiserv/pmiserv_pmci.c:77): unable to send signal downstream
[mpiexec@SOL] HYDT_dmxu_poll_wait_for_event (/usr/apps/lib/mpich-3.3.2/src/pm/hydra/tools/demux/demux_poll.c:77): callback returned error status
[mpiexec@SOL] HYD_pmci_wait_for_completion (/usr/apps/lib/mpich-3.3.2/src/pm/hydra/pm/pmiserv/pmiserv_pmci.c:196): error waiting for event
[mpiexec@SOL] main (/usr/apps/lib/mpich-3.3.2/src/pm/hydra/ui/mpich/mpiexec.c:336): process manager error waiting for completion
```

how can I fix the issue?

Comment: The missing file is from the PGI compiler runtime. You either need to install it on the local disk of `Corona`, or mount it from a shared filesystem on that node. `ssh SOL ldd /usr/apps/lib/mpich-3.3.2-pgf_gcc/examples/cpi |  grep libpgftnrtl.so` will show you where this file is found on `SOL`.

Comment: Just wonder should Icompile mpi statically? 
`shell$ ./configure --without-memory-manager --without-libnuma \
  --enable-static [...your other configure arguments...]`

Comment: Nope. But you might want to try linking the static PGI runtime (Intel has a flag for that, don’t know about PGI)